# QML: Keep c++ class in memory

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing an app in Qt quick.

In main.qml, I have QAbstractListModel which has a list of "areas". I am dynamically adding boxes (box.qml) to the areas with object createObject(). The box.qml contains a c++ class Handler created with qmlregistertype.

Now, when the area is not currently in the app view, the area gets destroyed. Problem is I need to be able to update Handler even if the box is out of the view.

Only thing I can think of is copying Handler to another pointer on destruction and then copy it back when the box is restored. This seems kind of heavy-duty to me.

Is there any way to simply prevent Handler from being destructed when the box is destructed?

Comment: Seems like you should have you have the QObject "handler" referenced by box.qml reference another data structure via reference/pointer or shared_ptr.  Separate your view objects from your actual data model and let things connect dynmically as ui elements are created on the fly.

Comment: Keep all your Handler instances in your QAbstractListModel (or QAbstractItemModel) and return only pointers (as QVariant) in `data()` method. Then you can bind these poiners with custom property of box.qml

Comment: I was playing around with the idea that I'd hold the Handler in QAbstractListModel but couldn't find a way to send pointers between qml and c++. It appears that at least QObject* can be passed around with QVariant. Hopefully it works with other pointers as well. Thank you both.